# ^ in jQuery selector does not work on IE

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors

I am debugging a piece of code where to select element from two different select elements, actually multiselct it uses something like this:

```
$('[id^=my_id]').on('click', '*', function() {
```

The reason is that the first select is

```
<select id="my_id_1"></select>
```

second one is:

```
<select id="my_id_2"></select>
```

The jQuery selector work just fine on chrome and firefox but it fails on IE/Edge
I was thinking to use classes instead of that selector, but since `^` selector is used a lot in the file I was wondering if there is a way to making it work with that type of selector.

When user clicks on each element that is listed on the mulitple select a div will appear next to it, containing further information about the option.
[image: Something like this:]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `click` is a useless event on a `<select>` in the first place. chances are IE isn't recognizing that event and problem has nothing to do with selector. Try using `change`. In other browsers click will fire more than once...opening select and then selecting option

Comment: Also get rid of `*`. Events are not supported at all on `<option>` in IE

Comment: I need the click on the element. It's a multiselct 'multiple' set to it. So I can use the onclick. on change won't be useful for what I need to do.

Comment: You aren't understanding.... click is not a proper event even for multiple. In IE there absolutely is no support for events on `<option>` and you can find many posts on this site to support that. Always use change on select

Comment: OK I see your new box on side. Another flaw in your UI is with multiple user can make or remove more than one choice at a time using keyboard/mouse combination. you have a design problem also. Consider using any number of `<select>` replacements scripts

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanation. It's working with the on change event. Just wondering why it was working with Chrome and Firefox...There is not much I can do with the UI, it locked as it is :( but I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: IE has always  had different api for `<select>` that always made it difficult to work with. I know some browsers will accept the events on option but that is not a spec and is not 100% cross browser. This issue has been around for years

Comment: Ok Thank you for your time! Lesson learned,

Comment: FYI--same problem in IE if you try to hide `<option>`...not supported but will work in some other browsers

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to this

```
 $('body').on('change', '[id^=my_id]', function() {

});
```

Comment: doesn't seem to fix my issue sorry. Might go for classes.

Answer (score 0):

You dnt need to use jquery always. If you say that the jquery selector is the problem, my suggestion is use HTML DOM queryselectorall:

```
document.querySelectorAll(CSS selectors).
```

For multiple selectors, separate each selector with a comma.

And add handler for event :

```
element.addEventListener(event, function,      useCapture);
```

And like @charlietfl said, the correct event is change no click.

Read:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Answer (score 0):

As charlietfl noticed in the comment my problem is with the `click` event and not with the selector. 
On a `select` I should use a `change` event.

```
$('[id^=my_id]').on('change', function() {
```